# Strange HTML code when scraping IEEEXPLORE

Tags: python, web-scraping, ieee

I am scraping the IEEEXplore for some data PDF, tile and links.

So recently when I scraping this site (with Python and twill module) I get similar this content:

```
��7���j��/�5�,X��]����O�s˟�����U|]�l
��c��qLE�[����:yg�u%��_�9e�;�4��^�kt)j�Te���:OX���[��u����B���-]?t�C���m/��ά��Ҋ��n�'��}'�Ù�ف{�S;�ƣ������3�dS��M[m
```

So why this is happening! I doubt about encoding of the page .!

the code is big but i inserted one part of those here:

you could see the code here:

https://github.com/power-electro/test-ieeexplore-scraper/blob/master/ieeexplore_ieee_org.py

So the Free PDF Files of ELsevier version of this site, is accessible via this link:

http://free-papers.elasa.ir

Comment: What is the link and where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to look at the rest of the output, but my guess is that all of that jumbled up stuff that's hard to read is actually an image file or a video file or something. Image and video files look very very weird when we try to HTTP GET them and print them out as text. My guess is that the normal website-scraping stuff you want (text, html, etc) is also in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer i removed th:is part of its header:

```
 t_com.add_extra_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')
```

this Data ore Gziped data.!!!

i de ziped data by this codes:

```
                content1 = t_brw.result.page
                # print 'debug twill post content:', content
                import StringIO
                content1 = StringIO.StringIO(content1)
                import gzip
                gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=content1)
                content = gzipper.read()
```